# Why are they padding only one shared memory?

Tags: cuda

- [An optimized handling of strided accesses using coalesced reads from global memory](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/10.2/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#shared-memory-in-matrix-multiplication-c-aa__optimized-version-coalesced-reads-global-memory)

The above link says that:

> ```
> __global__ void coalescedMultiply(float *a, float *c, int M)
> {
>   __shared__ float aTile[TILE_DIM][TILE_DIM],
>                    transposedTile[TILE_DIM][TILE_DIM];
>   int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
>   int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
>   float sum = 0.0f;
>   aTile[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x] = > a[row*TILE_DIM+threadIdx.x];
>   transposedTile[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y] =
>       a[(blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.y)*TILE_DIM +
>       threadIdx.x];  
>   __syncthreads();
>   for (int i = 0; i < TILE_DIM; i++) {
>       sum += aTile[threadIdx.y][i]* transposedTile[i][threadIdx.x];
>   }
>   c[row*M+col] = sum;
> }
> ```
>
> (...)
> These many-way bank conflicts are very expensive. The simple remedy is to pad the shared memory array so that it has an extra column, as in the following line of code.
>
> ```
> __shared__ float transposedTile[TILE_DIM][TILE_DIM+1];
> ```

My question is,

Why are they padding only right-hand-side (`transposedTile`) shared memory, not both (`transposedTile` and `aTile`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because only the access to that tile will exhibit bank conflicts, based on the access patterns in the code.  Therefore only that tile needs to be padded to avoid bank conflicts.

Briefly, bank conflicts in shared access occur when 2 or more threads in the warp are attempting to access values in the same bank, in the same transaction (basically like saying in the same instruction issue).  For simplicity, when we have a 32x32 threadblock array, and a 32x32 tile arrangement of 4-byte quantities, then *banks* and *columns* are synonymous.  Therefore the previous statement can be modified to say if two or more threads are accessing the same column in the tile, in the same cycle, there will be bank conflicts.

The exception to this rule is the broadcast exception.  If two or more threads are accessing the same bank (or column in this case) **because** they are accessing the same location, then that location will be broadcast to all necessary threads for that cycle, and the broadcast rule does not imply bank conflicts.

So this means we must look at all the access patterns (load and store) for each tile, and see which ones in the original code would be bank-conflicted.  Our rule is a bank conflict will occur if the *column* is the same between threads in a warp, but the *row* is different.  We should also be able to observe or quickly realize the general "layout" of a 32x32 threadblock: there are 32 warps in that threadblock.  In the first warp, all threads will have `threadIdx.y` equal to zero, and `threadIdx.x` varying from 0 to 31 across the warp.  The only difference for the second warp is that its `threadIdx.y` values will all be 1.  And 2 for the 3rd warp, and so on.

Now lets look at each access (one load and one store for each tile) and see which ones will have a bank-conflicted pattern in the original code:

```
aTile[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x] = ...
```

This is the store operation for `aTile`.  `threadIdx.y` is in the row index, and `threadIdx.x` is in the column index. We know that for a given warp in a 32x32 threadblock, `threadIdx.y` is constant across the warp, and `threadIdx.x` varies across the warp in a linear way: 0,1,2,3,...31.  Therefore, this shared load transaction will have threads asking for data in the same row of shared memory, and no bank conflicts will occur.  Each thread is reading from a separate column, which is like saying a separate bank in this case, and that is the canonically best pattern for shared memory: no bank conflicts.

```
transposedTile[threadIdx.x][threadIdx.y] = ...
```

This is the shared store transaction for `transposedTile`.  We see that compared to the previous case, the indexing is reversed.  `threadIdx.y`, which is constant across a warp, is now in the column index, and `threadIdx.x` which varies across the warp, is in the row index.   This means that we are selecting a single column across the warp, with different threads accessing different members of that column.  This is columnar access (instead of row-wise access in the previous case) and when we have a tile arrangement such that each column corresponds to a bank of shared memory, this will be canonically the worst possible access pattern into shared memory.  All threads are accessing the same bank, and warp-wide we will have a 32-way bank conflict, which means that the access will take 32 times longer than the best possible case.

```
... * transposedTile[i][threadIdx.x];
```

this is the load-from-shared operation for `transposedTile`. `i` is constant across the warp (in any given loop iteration), and `threadIdx.x` varies across the warp.  Therefore we are selecting a particular row, and asking for the elements along that row.  This is the best case for shared access.

```
sum += aTile[threadIdx.y][i] ...
```

Considered across the warp, this has both row and column fixed/constant in any given loop iteration.  This is the *broadcast* case.  In any given loop iteration and instruction issue cycle, every thread in the warp is asking for the same *location* in shared memory. It is also canonically good.

Therefore only 1 of the 4 possible access patterns has the potential to be bank conflicted.  This access pattern pertains to `transposedTile`, and therefore only `transposedTile` needs to be padded, to avoid bank conflicts in this code.